# Appending a line in a file to a variable

Tags: python, file, search, append

I need search a file for a username (the username is stored in a variable called x), and if x matches a line in the file, append the line exactly 2 lines below that into another variable (which will be called y). How would I do this?

I am fairly new to this, and don’t have access to my original code. I have remembered what I can about the code and contents of the file, and since I am inexperienced it’s pretty simplistic:

Example content of file:

```
Steven Abbot
qwerty
london
```

Example of code:

```
x = input(“Enter name:”)
password = (“Enter password:”)
city = (“Enter city name”)
crd = open(“credentials.txt”, “a”)
crd.write(x)
crd.write(\n)
crd.write(password)
crd.write(\n)
crd.write(city)
crd.write(\n)
crd.close()
```

Note that this programme is to be used several times, so I cannot simply append the the third line to y. The city name is the piece of information I need to extract and append to a variable called y. I am stuck since the city name can vary between users, and I do not know how to select and 2 lines below the name.

With the example content of the file, y would end up containing “london”, since it is two lines below x.

Comment: Hello! can you paste your source file and the python file you wrote in order for us to see where you're stuck?

Comment: I have edited and included the code, although it’s nothing special and could certainly use improving. Currently I am only concerned at the task I have described

Comment: Could you show what you would like as an output and what you are currently getting?

Comment: Currently I do not need an output since I only wish to append to a variable called y. As I do not know how to approach this, I was hoping to apply any answers here to what I have already got. All I have shown is all I have.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
def get_password(name, filename):
    textfile = file(filename)
    found = False
    skip = 0 
    for line in textfile :
        if found == False            
            if line == name:
                found = True  
        else
            skip = skip + 1
            if skip == 2
                return line

    return None # if name not found or password not found return  None
```

and then call:

```
get_password(x, “credentials.txt”)
```